# Dynamic column list for SSIS file load

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have been given a file that is broken into sections. Sections are delimited by "start-of-<sectionName>" and "end-of-<sectionname>" lines. The two sections that I'm concerned about are a list of fields and the actual data. Here's a brief example:

```
start-of-fields
a
b
c
end-of-fields
start-of-data
1|2|3
2|3|4
end-of-data
```

My problem comes in where a given file might not have all of the fields. What fields the file ***does*** have are listed in the fields section. Is there a way in a Script Component in the data flow task to parse out what columns are present and then parse the data section accordingly? I currently have a working Script Component (C#) that ignores the fields section and is assuming that all of the columns are there. I noticed in the parent class to my task's output buffer that there's a member called BufferColumnIndexes, but it's protected so I can't get at it from my script.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, a script component can read the input file line-by-line. When it found the `start-of-fields` line, it could build up a nice little array of column headers, stopping when it reached the `end-of-fields` line. Then it could read each line between the `start-of-data` and `end-of-data` lines, parse out the values, and add a row to an output buffer with the provided values and whatever you want for defaults.

However, that's an awful lot of stateful coding. Since you can't actually debug script components in SSIS 2008, getting it to work will be a real pain.

You might well be better off writing a full-blown custom data flow component. Or even writing a completely separate console application.